# Estimating fractional moments

Tags: estimation, moments

Suppose I want to estimate the $p$-th centered moment, where $p$ is a real number (in other words, I want to estimate $\int_{-\infty}^\infty |x|^p d \mu(x),$ where $p$ is, say $1.1$). What is the standard error from the sample $p$-th moment? There is a standard formula for $p=2$ and $\mu$ the Gaussian measure, but this is all I know (and even the result for Gaussians would be welcome). Also, as we all know, the sample variance is not an unbiased estimator of the variance, so presumably something like that is true for general $p.$

Comment: You observe numbers $x_i.$  By considering the $|x_i|^p$ as your data, you are asking how to compute the standard error of the mean, reducing the question to a familiar one whose answer you know.

Comment: @whuber true, but I am guessing that the bias will be LARGER than for $p=2,$ so the bias is the really significant part of the question...

Comment: The bias will depend on the underlying distribution.  Estimating that bias is of little general interest, although possibly in a particular situation it could be useful to know.